# Using Scrapy: how to download pdf files from some extracted links

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've created code that extracts some links from a website (PDF links,) and now I need to download these PDF files, but I am struggling with how to do that. This is the code:

```py
    import scrapy


    class all5(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "all5"
        start_urls = [
          'https://www.alloschool.com/course/alriadhiat-alaol-ibtdaii',
        ]

        def parse(self, response):


            for link in response.css('.default .er').xpath('@href').extract():
                 url=response.url
                 path=response.css('ol.breadcrumb li a::text').extract()
                 next_link = response.urljoin(link)
                 yield scrapy.Request(next_link,callback=self.parse_det,meta={'url' : url,'path':path})

        def parse_det(self, response):

            def extract_with_css(query):
                return response.css(query).get(default='').strip()

            yield {
                'path':response.meta['path'],
                'finallink': extract_with_css('a.btn.btn-primary::attr(href)'),
                'url':response.meta['url']

                }
```

The links that I need to download are "finallink".

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: scrapy doc: [Downloading and processing files and images](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In settings you have to activate pipeline

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1}
```

and folder for downloaded files

```
'FILES_STORE' = '.'
```

It will download to `FILES_STORE/full`

And you have to use name `files_url` when you yield data

```
yield {
    'file_urls': [extract_with_css('a.btn.btn-primary::attr(href)')]
    # ... rest ...
}
```

It has to be list even if you has one file to download.

It should download PDFs to files with unique names which you get in data in field `files`

---

Scrapy doc: [Downloading and processing files and images](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html)

---

**EDIT:** standalone code - you can copy and run without creating project.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = [
          'https://www.alloschool.com/course/alriadhiat-alaol-ibtdaii',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        for link in response.css('.default .er').xpath('@href').extract():
             url = response.url
             path = response.css('ol.breadcrumb li a::text').extract()
             next_link = response.urljoin(link)
             yield scrapy.Request(next_link, callback=self.parse_det, meta={'url': url, 'path': path})

    def parse_det(self, response):

        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).get(default='').strip()

        yield {
            'path':response.meta['path'],
            'file_urls': [extract_with_css('a.btn.btn-primary::attr(href)')],
            'url':response.meta['url']
        }


from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in file as CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', # 

    # download files to `FILES_STORE/full`
    # it needs `yield {'file_urls': [url]}` in `parse()`
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1},
    'FILES_STORE': '.',
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @furas .I've tried what you suggested to me and it has downloaded only the files in the main link : https://www.alloschool.com/course/alriadhiat-alaol-ibtdaii  ##But in the code,there is a following link to another link where it has to get the finallink pdf from ('a.btn.btn-primary::attr(href)'

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you have link to another page then use `Request()` to get this page and parse - and then get link to PDF which you use in `yield`

Comment: Yes,that's what i did,but i still don't get any pdf files saved in my folder :/

Comment: two things to correction: (1) `file_urls` has to be list - even if you have one file to download. (2) it needs also `FILE_STORE` with folder's name for downloaded files. It will download to `FILE_STORE/full`. I added full working code in answer. It downloads PDFs for me. You can run it without creating project.

Comment: Thank you so much,it works now ! By the way,is there any possibility to save the files with their original name they get from the website,because here the files are saved with random caracters.

Comment: you would have to write own `FilesPipeline` and change function which generate name for downloaded file.

Comment: Alright.Thank you @furas , i appreciate your help !