# Extract data from a table including files using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am attempting to extract data from a table that shows a list of active bids here: https://purchasing.alabama.gov/active-statewide-contracts/. I am a Scrapy newbie, and bit stuck as to why I get no output. Additionally, how do I download files found within the table? I have the following code so far:

```
import scrapy

class AlabamaSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'alabama'
allowed_domains = ['purchasing.alabama.gov']
start_urls = ['https://purchasing.alabama.gov/active-statewide-contracts/']

def start_requests(self):
    urls = ['https://purchasing.alabama.gov/active-statewide-contracts/']

    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
   
def parse(self, response):
    for row in response.xpath('//*[@class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm dataTable no-footer"]//tbody//tr'):

        yield {
                'Description': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-5 sorting_asc"]//text()').extract_first(),
                'T-NBR': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1 sorting"]/a/text()').extract_first(),
                'Begin Date': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1 sorting"]//text()').extract_first(),
                'End Date': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1 sorting"]//text()').extract_first(),
                'Buyer Name': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-3 sorting"]/a/text()').extract_first(),
                'Vendor Websites': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1 sorting"]/a/text()').extract_first(),
}
```

Any help to this end will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: please check the solution & let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tips and the solution @Shivam it worked!! One last thing, any pointers on how to download the files (they are all pdf files) under the 'T-BNR' column? Thanks again!

Comment: I guess this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245315/using-scrapy-how-to-download-pdf-files-from-some-extracted-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new to Scrapy, my advice would be:

- You can either use `start_urls` property or `start_requests()` method. But, avoid using both in the same code. You can read more about it from [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) .
- No need to iterate through urls as you are making request only one time.
- Your code is not producing the output because your `XPath` is incorrect.

**Code**

```
import scrapy

class AlabamaSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'alabama'
    allowed_domains = ['purchasing.alabama.gov']

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://purchasing.alabama.gov/active-statewide-contracts/'

        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//*[@class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm"]//tbody//tr'):

            yield {
                'Description': row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[@class="col-sm-5"])').extract_first(),
                'T-NBR': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1"]/a//text()').extract_first(),
                'Begin Date': row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[@class="col-sm-1"][2])').extract_first(),
                'End Date': row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[@class="col-sm-1"][3])').extract_first(),
                'Buyer Name': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-3"]/a//text()').extract_first(),
                'Vendor Websites': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1"]/label/text()').extract_first(),
            }
```